# How to ignore that element doesn't exist and skip taking a screenshot?

Tags: playwright

I would like to take a screenshot of an element that might or might not exist

```
  const elem = await page.locator('.selector')
  await elem.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
  await elem.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});
```

If the element isn't on the page this results in

```
elementHandle.screenshot: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
```

Is there a way to just ignore the nonexistence and move on?

This behaves the same

```
const elem = await page.locator('.selector')
if(elem) {
  await elem.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
  await elem.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});
}
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping in a `try {} catch() {}`?

Comment: @MalwareMoon I didn't. That works, thanks! Please add it as an answer

Comment: Glad to help. Answer created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your logic in `try {} catch() {}` as the possible throw created by screenshot not existing is going to be passed to catch where it can be ignored, instead crashing runtime.